# Books and references for developing AR with google cardboard

Tags: android, augmented-reality, google-cardboard

good day!
I've been scouring the web for some reference on VR development with google cardboard, but i find it scarce, most of the reference just emphasize on VR. i am compelled to seek help here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying out Vuforia and it works great! http://developer.vuforia.com